# Create a vector of pairwise durations between many timepoints

Tags: r

Consider this set of time points:

```
time1 <- as.Date("2011/04/05")
time2 <- as.Date("2011/05/17")
time3 <- as.Date("2011/06/27")
time4 <- as.Date("2011/08/16")
time5 <- as.Date("2011/10/05")
time6 <- as.Date("2011/11/21")
```

I want to create a vector containing all pairwise durations between the time points. For 6 points in time, this is manageable, but already tedious:

```
time.elapsed <- as.numeric(c(abs(time1-time2),abs(time1-time3),
                             abs(time1-time4),abs(time1-time5),
                             abs(time1-time6),abs(time2-time3),
                             abs(time2-time4),abs(time2-time5),
                             abs(time2-time6),abs(time3-time4),
                             abs(time3-time5),abs(time3-time6),
                             abs(time4-time5),abs(time4-time6),
                             abs(time5-time6)))

time.elapsed
 [1]  42  83 133 183 230  41  91 141 188  50 100 147  50  97  47
```

How can i simplify this code for many more timepoints (say, 15 or 20)?
It would be nice to keep the format as above (first all durations between timepoint 1 and all others, then time point 2 and all others except 1, etc). Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will help you

```
df <- data.frame(time = c(time1, time2, time3, time4, time5, time6) )

outer( df$time, df$time , "-" )

Time differences in days
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    0  -42  -83 -133 -183 -230
[2,]   42    0  -41  -91 -141 -188
[3,]   83   41    0  -50 -100 -147
[4,]  133   91   50    0  -50  -97
[5,]  183  141  100   50    0  -47
[6,]  230  188  147   97   47    0
```

to get your preferred outcome, get the lower triangle of the matrix

```
outer( df$time, df$time , "-" )[lower.tri( outer( df$time, df$time , "-" ) )]

Time differences in days
 [1]  42  83 133 183 230  41  91 141 188  50 100 147  50  97  47
```

Comment: Thank you very much! unique() is missing one value, because one duration is duplicated (abs(time3-time4) is as long as abs(time4-time5)). Maybe some sort of vectorizing the lower tri of the matrix?

Answer (score 1):

There is another solution using `sapply`:

```
# Data from the example
dt <- as.Date(c("2011/04/05", 
                "2011/05/17", 
                "2011/06/27", 
                "2011/08/16", 
                "2011/10/05", 
                "2011/11/21")
              )
# Difftime with sapply
unlist(sapply(seq_along(dt), function(i) difftime(dt[-(1:i)], dt[i])))
# [1]  42  83 133 183 230  41  91 141 188  50 100 147  50  97  47
```

The difference between @Wimpel approach and mine is negligible until we are working with *small datasets*. But, with relatively *big datasets* you will notice the difference in performance (on my laptop I can see it starting from N > 500):

[image: sapply vs outer - performance]

Off course `sapply` doesn't really outperforms `outer` so much. Using both approaches you can work only with *relatively small datasets*. However, it seems that it is better to use `sapply` in case when the length of your dataset is greater than several hundreds.

Moreover on my computer, when `N = 5500` `outer` crashes with `Error: cannot allocate vector of size 230.8 Mb` but `sapply` still works even when `N = 15000` with elapsed time something around 90 seconds. You can check it out on your machine, [there is a code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dpdiw8zqdrpr65i/50855897.R?dl=0).